# why i can't find blk0001.bat and blkindex.bat on my computer

Tags: bitcoin-core

my bitcoin-qt client'data is at the "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\Bitcoin", but i can't find the blk0001.bat and blkindex.bat two files on this dir

Answer (score 2):

The extension of file names you are looking for is `.dat`, not `.bat`.